# Calcular el residuo de un valor total diferido a cuotas y agregarlo a un jtable?

Tags: java, java-swing

```
  private void PLAN_DE_PAGO_CREDITO() {
    int cntCuotas = 14;
    int totalVrCredito = 1.400.000;
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) TB_PLAN_PAGO.getModel();
    for (int i = 1; i <= cntCuotas ; i++) {
        int valorCuota = totalVrCredito/cntCuotas;
        totalVrCredito = totalVrCredito - valorCuota;
       //            System.out.println("Letra No: "+i+" - 
          ValorCuota: $ "+valorCuota);

        System.out.println("Letra No: "+i+" - 
         ValorSaldoCuota: $ "+totalVrCredito);

     }

     }
```

hola buen dia, quizas no sea un tema muy relevante y que se deba colocar aqui mil disculpas si es asi. Pero ya he probado realizarlo por mi cuenta y no me a resultado y ps por tal razon llego a ustedes quien me pueda ayudar desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Has probado con el método `TB_PLAN_PAGO.setValueAt`?

Comment: No lo he ensayado aun. Por que primero lo que se quiere es saber como calcular el saldo restante despues de pagar una cuota. Y posteriormente añadir la lista a la tabla.

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los datos que deben ser tomados en cuenta en el cálculo?

Comment: Ej: totalvrcredito = 1.000.000 y cntCuotas = 10. ValorCuota = totalvrcredito/cntCuota. Cual es el TotalSaldo en cada cuota calculada?

Comment: ¿Ese cálculo no lo realizas dentro del `for`?

Comment: Apenas tengo el calculo del valor de la cuota. El valor del saldo no se donde debe ir ni se como se calcula

Comment: El valor del cálculo, lo obtienes aquí: `int valorCuota = totalVrCredito/cntCuotas;`, y justo aquí: `totalVrCredito = totalVrCredito - valorCuota;` obtienes el saldo restante (lo que te falta por cancelar)

Comment: Si tienes `1.000.000` la primera vez, y realizas el cálculo, (`1.000.000 / 10 = 100.000`), ese valor de cuota lo restas al total (`1.000.000 - 100.000 = 900.000`), es decir, el saldo que te falta por cancelar son `900.000`

Comment: Ese procedimiento se realizará la cantidad de veces que se realice el bucle del `for`, es decir, se hará `10` veces (porque `cntCuota` es `10`)

Comment: En un principio lo tenia de esa forma totalVrCredito = totalVrCredito - valorCuota pero me arroja un resultado "incorrecto". Acabo de hacerlo de la misma forma pero declarando antes del for una variable y almacenando el valor de totalVrCredito en ella. Asi saldoCuota = saldoCuota - valorCuota dentro del for y hay si me funciono. Muchisimas gracias por todo.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el valor que debería esperarse, por ejemplo, la primera vez?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75308/discussion-between-c-rodriguez-and-jose-felix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Saludos Jose Felix.

Lo que pasa es que estabas recalculando el `valorCuota` dentro del `for`, y por esta causa, cada vez que se recalculaba, el `valorCuota` cambia su valor, y tú lo que quieres es mantener el mismo valor. Lo que puedes hacer es calcular una sola vez `valorCuota` antes del `for` (así no tendrías que crear otra variable como `saldoCuota` (que indicaste en los comentarios):

```
public void PLAN_DE_PAGO_CREDITO() {
    int cntCuotas = 14;
    int totalVrCredito = 1400000;

    int valorCuota = totalVrCredito / cntCuotas; // se calcula el valorCuota una sola vez

    for (int i = 1; i <= cntCuotas; i++) {
        totalVrCredito = totalVrCredito - valorCuota; // solamente se resta ese valorCuota

        System.out.println("Letra No: " + i + " - ValorCuota: $ " + valorCuota);
        System.out.println("Letra No: " + i + " - ValorSaldoCuota: $ " + totalVrCredito);
    }
}
```